# How to override/enhance file_save_upload() function of file.inc?

Tags: 7, media

For a specific requirement, wherein whenever an image is uploaded to a particular field of a node, a watermark should be added to it, I made changes in file_save_upload() function of file.inc

```
if (!drupal_move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$source], $file->uri)) {
    form_set_error($source, t('File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.'));
    watchdog('file', 'Upload error. Could not move uploaded file %file to destination    %destination.', array('%file' => $file->filename, '%destination' => $file->uri));
   return FALSE;
}
else{
    process_image(drupal_realpath($file->uri));
}
```

But these changes will be lost whenever Drupal core will be upgraded. So what is the best way to override/enhance file_save_upload() function of file.inc or any function in the core drupal?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal runs on a [Never hack core](https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) policy.

The Drupal way to add a watermark to image is to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to modify the form submit and do your things with `$form_state['values']['YOUR_FIELD']`

Eg:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {
  switch ($form_id)  {
   case 'YOURFORMID':
     $form['#submit'][] = 'yourModule_yourform_submit';
     break;
   }
 }

function yourModule_yourform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    // do what you want to do 
    // use $form_state['values']
}
```

Or Try [ImageCache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) module.

> Watermarking - a much requested addition that enables you to place any
>   image anywhere over a source picture, with alpha transparency

Comment: So, Do I need to create a module for this particular requirement?

Comment: There already is a module, Imagecache Actions: https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions

Comment: @PatrickKenny - Image Actions, as far as I know, are leaving original file intact and create their "after actions" copy separately? Or do I recall it wrong? Long time since I was playing with images, maybe I'm confused with 6.x imagecache, so could you clarify?

Comment: @Molot Yes, Imagecache Actions are applied via image styles, not upon upload.  However, using styles for all images and disallowing access to the original files is faster than writing a new module if that fits the use case.

Comment: I just thought that in that case it's worth to mention that unaltered files will still be there so one needs to be careful ih he does not want them to get downloaded.